# Url rewrite and getting a parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to rewrite my urls:

From this:
`https://example.com/try`

To this:
`https://example.com/en/try`

In the meantimes, I need to have a condition for FR content where the url should be: `https://example.com/fr/essayer`.

So I have actually this code:

```
RewriteRule en/login login.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
RewriteRule fr/connexion login.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]
```

It's looks working but I can't retrieve the lang parameter.

How can I make this ?

Comment: It's not clear enough for me. How many rewrite rules do you need? Can you list them using a clean and clear ordering?

Comment: @EduardoEscobar: here what it can help you: https://jsfiddle.net/xpgjyejn/. Thanks.

Comment: So `en/login` is correctly rewritten to `login.php` but you can't grab `lang` parameter within it? I mean, using `$_REQUEST['lang']` ?

Comment: You're right. I can with `$_REQUEST['lang']`or `$_GET['lang']`.

Comment: So what's the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

From your https://jsfiddle.net/xpgjyejn/ code . I m seeing that you wrote these two lines for removing extension(i.e., to internally redirect to the file with .php extension)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So when user searches for

```
/en/brand
```

internally it will search for

```
/en/brand.php
```

It has L flag and it stops execution.So none of your code next to that line is executed. As you already wrote all the rewrite rules in your .htaccess file comment out these two lines by adding # infront of them

```
   # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   # RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now your code will be

```
 RewriteEngine On

    # Removing extension
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

    # Redirect rewrite urls
    # brand
    RewriteRule en/brand brand.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule fr/marque brand.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]

    # conditions
    RewriteRule en/conditions conditions.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule fr/conditions conditions.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]

    # contact
    RewriteRule en/contact contact.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule fr/contact contact.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]

    # features
    RewriteRule en/features features.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule fr/fonctionnalites features.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]

    # forgot-password
    RewriteRule en/forgot-password forgot-password.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule fr/mot-de-pass-oublie forgot-password.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]



    # login
    RewriteRule en/login login.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule fr/connexion login.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]

    # pricing
    RewriteRule en/pricing pricing.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule fr/tarification pricing.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]

    # try
    RewriteRule en/try try.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule fr/essayer try.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]

 # index
    RewriteRule en/ index.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule fr/ index.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hello, when I try reaching out the url `example.com/fr/essayer` or anything else, I jump to the home page content. I think it's cause by the `index`rules. How can I change this please?

Comment: yeah thats because you added these two lines in the middle `# index
RewriteRule en/ index.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
RewriteRule fr/ index.php?lang=fr [L,QSA]`
 To Overcome that move them to the bottom . I changed the code in my answer check that

Comment: And how can I get the `en` or `fr` parameters ? `$_GET['lang']` or `$_REQUEST['lang']` don't work.

Comment: See that should work. Check this link http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=7a084b3d-5e3e-5c1f-849c-005ef123fb29